# How to set artifactId when publishing Kotlin Multiplatform Project to mavenLocal?

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

Background: I have a kotlin multiplatform project to publish to mavenLocal for use in another project. I'd like to be able to set the artifactId but this seems to be set elsewhere. After the publishToMavenLocal command executes and the project has been published locally the artifactId seems to be prefixed by a string from settings.gradle.kts specifically, `include(":kotlin-xtype")`

Example Output: [Publishing Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ht3H.jpg)

How can I set the artifactId outside of the settings.gradle? I've tried adding `artifactId = "xyz"` in the publishing block of build.gradle but this only changed the names of the metadata and multiplatform artifacts and didn't change the jvm or js artifacts.

Here is some of my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins{
    `maven-publish`
    kotlin("multiplatform") version("1.4.20") //Version.kotlin)
    application
}

application {
    group = "nz.salect.xtypes"

    version = "0.0.2"
    mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"
}
val javadocJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    from(tasks.getByName("javadoc"))
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
}
//// The root publication also needs a sources JAR as it does not have one by default
val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.value("sources")
}
publishing {
    publications.withType<MavenPublication>().all {
        artifact(javadocJar)
        artifactId = "xyz"
    }
}

publishing.publications.withType<MavenPublication>().getByName("kotlinMultiplatform").artifact(sourcesJar)
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15731. I ended up setting the Gradle project name to match the artifact id. Not great but works for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for the publication name, and act accordingly.

Here's an example in Kotlin, supposing you have the id you want in the `artifactId` variable:

```kotlin
publishing {
  publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
    if (name == "kotlinMultiplatform") {
      setArtifactId(artifactId)
    } else {
      setArtifactId("$artifactId-$name")
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your publications block to generate the missing artifacts.

```
artifact(sourcesJar)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP isn't missing artifacts but the artifact's id is taken from the library name instead of the artifactId definition configured for the Maven publication.